# excel look for same value and calculate value from next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table, named ART_NR, It has number values in it, i need a function which looks for the same values in that column and calculates it accordingly for the column MENGE.
So it looks on column ART_NR for the same numbers and then calculates all the values together on the column MENGE. So if ART_NR has the value "1" lets say 10 times, it calculates on the column MENGE how much correspondes to ART_NR "1".

I left a picture as a example cause im having a bit of a hard time explaining it, but basically i need it to to calculate everything from the same value of ART_NR from the table MENGE

[image]

Comment: So, does the MENGE column showing the expected output, in the screenshot you have shared ?

Comment: ART_NR Is the article number, example "1" Would be cheese, and MENGE is the amount of it.

Comment: So ART_NR "1" MENGE "585"
I need it to find in ART_NR all the values that have "1" for example and then add up all the values from ART_NR "1" in MENGE

Comment: May be something like this `=SUMPRODUCT(($B2=$B$2:$B$17)*($F$2:$F$17))` where Column B `ART_NR` & Column F `MENGE`

Comment: http://prnt.sc/26mplco

Comment: This is what i got, Further explaining is, ART_NR i only need it to find the same values, and then from those values calculate it into corresponding MENGE column.

Comment: Its better if you show me a screenshot with before output and after output.